# How to separate this into 2 separate columns?

Tags: java, string

AntS
Ant
BearS
Bear
CatS
Cat
DogS
Dog
FalconS
Falcon

```
String five = word;
String Sremove = five.replace("s", "S");
            
System.out.println(Sremove);
    
        
//Display without plurals
String remove = word;
String withoutS = remove.replace("s"," ");
  
System.out.println(withoutS);
```

What I want is the 1st column are the words without plurals, and the 2nd column are the one with plurals.

I can't find solutions so I went here

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Let's clarify your question before writing any code.  Are you taking a list of words and filtering them, separating them in two groups?  Or are you modifying the words?

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] words = {"Ants", "Bears", "Cats", "Dogs", "Falcons"};

    System.out.println("Without plurals\tWith plurals");
    for (String word : words) {
        String withoutS = word.replaceAll("s$", "");
        System.out.println(withoutS + "\t\t\t" + word);
    }
```

Output:

```
Without plurals With plurals
Ant         Ants
Bear            Bears
Cat         Cats
Dog         Dogs
Falcon          Falcons
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic implementation, to generate 2 columns of `String` values.

```java
String columns(String string) {
    String[] strings = string.split(" ");
    int widthA = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < strings.length; index += 2) {
        if (strings[index].length() > widthA)
            widthA = strings[index].length();
    }
    int widthB = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < strings.length; index += 2) {
        if (strings[index + 1].length() > widthB)
            widthB = strings[index + 1].length();
    }
    StringBuilder columns = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0; index < strings.length; index += 2) {
        columns.append(("%-" + widthB + "s ").formatted(strings[index + 1]));
        columns.append(("%-" + widthA + "s%n").formatted(strings[index]));
    }
    return columns.toString();
}
```

Output using the data you provided, is as follows.

```
Ant    AntS   
Bear   BearS  
Cat    CatS   
Dog    DogS   
Falcon FalconS
```

Alternately, if you are looking for two arrays, as opposed to two text columns, you can use the following method.

```java
String[][] columns(String string) {
    String[] strings = string.split(" ");
    String[][] columns = new String[2][strings.length / 2];
    for (int indexA = 0, indexB = 0; indexA < strings.length; indexA += 2, indexB++) {
        columns[0][indexB] = strings[indexA + 1];
        columns[1][indexB] = strings[indexA];
    }
    return columns;
}
```

If we printed the data, we'd get the following output.

```
[Ant, Bear, Cat, Dog, Falcon]
[AntS, BearS, CatS, DogS, FalconS]
```